# How to manually colour sunburst() chart so that leafs are different shade of same colour to parent leaf?

Tags: r, colors, sunburst-diagram

I want to manually colour a sunburst chart where layers that branch from the inner circle is the same colour but a different shade as you move out from the center. In my particular dataframe I therefore want all parts of the circles (from the 2'nd circle to the last circle) that branch out from defined `Taxa` groups (i.e., the first circle - parent leaf) to be different shades of the same colour. For example, where I have `Cetacea` in my first circle I will colour orange, and every circle portion branching from this group will be a different shade of orange moving from darker to lighter as you move towards the outer circle. Is this possible? Any idea how to do this?

Here is a sample of my dataframe

```
df = structure(list(V1 = c("Cephalopoda - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cephalopoda - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Habitat and space use - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cephalopoda - Saltwater - Conservation Methods - Hypoxic Zones - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cephalopoda - Saltwater - Other Drivers of Movement and Habitat Use - Environmental factors - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cephalopoda - Saltwater - Other Drivers of Movement and Habitat Use - Seasonal Differences - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - >40m - NA - Medium Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Co_existence - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Co_existence - >40m - NA - Medium Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Cooperative Behaviour - 3m to 40m - Medium - Medium Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Energetics - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Energetics - >40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Predator prey interactions - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Predator prey interactions - >40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Methodological - Feasibility - Surface to 3m - Medium - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Methodological - Feasibility - Surface to 3m - NA - Short Term - Short term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Methodological - Feasibility - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Methodological - Tagging procedure - Surface to 3m - Medium - NA - NA - Satellite - Stationary", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Other Drivers of Movement and Habitat Use - Environmental factors - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Other Drivers of Movement and Habitat Use - Ice cover and shift - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Reproductive Ecology - Parental offspring interactions - Surface to 3m - Medium - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Reproductive Ecology - Parental offspring interactions - Surface to 3m - NA - Short Term - Short term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Chondrichthyes - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - 3m to 40m - Medium - Long Term - Long Term - Acoustic_Satellite - BRUV", 
                           "Chondrichthyes - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - 3m to 40m - Large - Medium Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Chondrichthyes - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - >40m - Large - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Chondrichthyes - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Co_existence - >40m - NA - Medium Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Chondrichthyes - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Community structuring - Surface to 3m - Small - Long Term - Short term - Acoustic - BRUV"
), total = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                         -27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and here the code I am using

```
library(sunburstR)
p = sunburst(df)
p
```

An example of what I am looking for is something like this. Please note that it is the progression of colour, and colour groupings that are important here. The lines are not exactly where they fall when you run my code
[image]

Comment: Bro you mean for each (-) need circle?

Cephalopoda(1st circle parent) - Saltwater(2nd circle child21) - Behavioural Ecology(3rd circle child31) - Behavioural states and adaptations - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne" ?

Comment: Kristen, give me some input man.

Comment: I am referring to the circle parent as the first ring of circles. So Colours should correspond to the labels in the first ring of circles (i.e., Cephalopoda, Cetacea etc.). Which means that every other circle ring WITHIN that first circle group should be the same colour but a different shade

Comment: If you can explain just draw

Comment: @R.G.Krish does this make more sense?

Comment: Cool, Let me check

Comment: 1. 1st level circle values (Cephalopoda, Cetacea, Chondrichthyes) right(this one understood)

2. what about the 2nd and 3rd level circle? can you give me which data will come to the respective circle?

Comment: It's the exact order that is in the dataframe, i.e., ```Cephalopoda - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne``` is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think supplying a JavaScript `function` will likely be the best method to achieve your goal.  Will you please try the following and let me know if this is in the right direction?

```
library(sunburstR)

df = structure(list(V1 = c("Cephalopoda - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cephalopoda - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Habitat and space use - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cephalopoda - Saltwater - Conservation Methods - Hypoxic Zones - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cephalopoda - Saltwater - Other Drivers of Movement and Habitat Use - Environmental factors - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cephalopoda - Saltwater - Other Drivers of Movement and Habitat Use - Seasonal Differences - NA - Medium - Medium Term - NA - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - >40m - NA - Medium Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Co_existence - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Co_existence - >40m - NA - Medium Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Cooperative Behaviour - 3m to 40m - Medium - Medium Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Energetics - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Energetics - >40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Predator prey interactions - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Predator prey interactions - >40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Methodological - Feasibility - Surface to 3m - Medium - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Methodological - Feasibility - Surface to 3m - NA - Short Term - Short term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Methodological - Feasibility - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Methodological - Tagging procedure - Surface to 3m - Medium - NA - NA - Satellite - Stationary", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Other Drivers of Movement and Habitat Use - Environmental factors - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Other Drivers of Movement and Habitat Use - Ice cover and shift - 3m to 40m - NA - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Reproductive Ecology - Parental offspring interactions - Surface to 3m - Medium - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Cetacea - Saltwater - Reproductive Ecology - Parental offspring interactions - Surface to 3m - NA - Short Term - Short term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Chondrichthyes - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - 3m to 40m - Medium - Long Term - Long Term - Acoustic_Satellite - BRUV", 
                           "Chondrichthyes - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - 3m to 40m - Large - Medium Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Chondrichthyes - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Behavioural states and adaptations - >40m - Large - Short Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Chondrichthyes - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Co_existence - >40m - NA - Medium Term - Medium Term - Archival - AnimalBorne", 
                           "Chondrichthyes - Saltwater - Behavioural Ecology - Community structuring - Surface to 3m - Small - Long Term - Short term - Acoustic - BRUV"
), total = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
             1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                         -27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
sunburst(
  df,
  withD3 = TRUE,
  colors= htmlwidgets::JS("
function() {
  debugger
  // this will be d3 version 4
  const node = d3.select(this).datum()
  let color
  
  if(node.depth > 0) {  // 2nd level
    const ancestors = node.depth === 1 ? [node.parent, node] : node.ancestors().reverse()
    // inefficient to define every time but will do this way for now
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
      .domain(ancestors[0].children.map(d=>d.data.name))
    return(d3.color(color(ancestors[1].data.name)).brighter((node.depth - 1)/4))
  }
}
  ")
)
```

[image: screenshot of sunburst]

Answer (score -1):

Try the below example from your input,

```
library(sunburstR)
#sunburstR::sunburst(unname(df)) #1st example
sunburstR::sunburst(unname(df), colors= list("#ebf1f5", "#cae7fa", "#afdcfa", "#91d0fa", "#6ec2fa", "#4bb4fa", "#28a4f7", "#0a9afa", "#0365a6", "#012d4a")) #2nd example
```

[image: Sunbrust Image]
[image]

Comment: The colours do not match. You can see that where there is dark orange in the first ring, then everything corresponding to that dark orange includes other colours like green, purple, blue. This does not look like the example I drew and provided in the question. And there is nowhere in this code that manually specifies colours

Comment: Check the 2nd example.

Comment: Right, as stated in my questions. I am looking for a different colour for each group in the inner circle. So ```cetacea``` and ```cephalopoda``` should be different colours, but every section that corresponds to those groups should be the same colour but a different shade - as shown in my example picture. And I want the shades to move from darker to lighter as you move out towards the last ring.